# Jaccard similarity in stringdist package to match words in character string

Tags: r, text, stringdist

I would like to use the Jaccard similarity in the stringdist function to determine the similarity of bags of words.  From what I can tell, using Jaccard only matches by letters within a character string.

```
c <- c('cat', 'dog', 'person')
d <- c('cat', 'dog', 'ufo')

stringdist(c, d, method='jaccard', q=2)
[1] 0 0 1
```

So we see here that it calculates the similarity of 'cat' and 'cat', 'dog' and 'dog' and 'person' and 'ufo'.

I also tried converting the words into 1 long text string.  The following approaches what I need, but it's still calculating 1 - (number of shared 2-grams / number of total unique 2-grams):

```
f <- 'cat dog person'
g <- 'cat dog ufo'
stringdist(f, g, method='jaccard', q=2)
[1] 0.5625
```

How would I get it to calculate similarity by the words?

Comment: Please explain better your desired outcome. The first instance calculates the difference between each word in order. Are you interested comparing two bags of words (unordered sets)?

Answer (score 5):

You can start by tokenizing the sentence and hashing the corresponding list of words to transform your sentences into list of integers, and then use `seq_dist()` to calculate the distance.

```
library(hashr); library(stringdist)
f <- 'cat dog person'
g <- 'cat dog ufo'
seq_dist(hash(strsplit(f, "\\s+")), hash(strsplit(g, "\\s+")), method = "jaccard", q = 2)
[1] 0.6666667
```

Comment: This measure could also be achieved in the OP's first example: `wordSim <- 1 - stringdist(c, d, method='jaccard', q=2); sum(wordSim) / length(wordSim)`.

Comment: I think for the example OP gives, yes. But generally it may not be correct. Consider this example `c <- c('cat', 'dog', 'person'); d <- c('cat', 'dog', 'upon'); stringdist(c, d, method='jaccard', q=2); [1] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.8571429`

Comment: These are interesting suggestions.  Thank you.  I was initially looking at the stringdist package as a faster alternative to just calculating the Jaccard similartiy manually:  `c <- c('cat', 'dog', 'person') d <- c('cat', 'dog', 'ufo') length(intersect(c, d)) / length(union(c,d))`.  It looks this simple method is the best.  It's interesting to note that this has 1 for highest similarity, whereas the stringdist formula has 0 for highest similarity.

Comment: @Psidom, I was hoping you would be able to share some solution to a similar query I had on usage of stringdistmatrix. I have posted the same as a question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486172/r-string-match-for-address-using-stringdist-stringdistmatrix    Hope you would be able to help!!